# iPhone loading view "slide effect"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I would to achieve that when you request something in my app (like a button pressed or whatever) I would like it to appear a small rectangle that says "loading.." and when the loading is completed it disappear with a "slide up effect". I've made a simple mockups for describing well what I'm trying to achieve. Do you have any hint for me? Thanks.

[image]

NOTE: **I don't want pull to refresh effect (the loading view appears without the screen scrolling, it appears for example when you send a comment)**

**UPDATE:**

I've tried the Cirrostratus code:

```
- (IBAction)displayLoadingScreen:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"pressed");
    UIView *loadingView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-40,320,40);
    [loadingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:loadingView];
    //animate in within some method called when loading starts
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{ 
                         loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,40);
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%d", i);
    }
    //animate out within some method called when loading ends
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{ 
                         loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-40,320,40);
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){


                     }];
}
```

Why the loading view slide in **after** the for loop? If you try it, before it prints the for loop and after executes the two animations. Ideas?

**UPDATE 2**

```
- (void)stopLoading {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{ 
                         loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-40,320,40);
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
}

- (void)startLoading {
    loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-40,320,40);
    [loadingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:loadingView];
    //animate in within some method called when loading starts
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{ 
                         loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,40);
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
    sleep(5);
    [self stopLoading];
}

- (IBAction)displayLoadingScreen:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"button pressed");
    [self startLoading];
}
```

Comment: Try reading `UIAnimation` class ( and using QuartzCore framework ).

Comment: Or, if you want to use Slide down to update feature like Facebook did, consider using `EGOTableViewPullRefresh`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-40,320,40);
[loadingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.view addSubview:loadingView];
//animate in within some method called when loading starts
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{ 
                     loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,40);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                 }];
//animate out within some method called when loading ends
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{ 
                     loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-40,320,40);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                 }];
```

Comment: In my answer I told you to to put those animations in separate methods, one to be called when loading starts and one when loading ends. The loops executes before the animation finishes because the animation takes 1 second the execute, which is done as other code continues. So, to recap—don't have both animations in the same method. Call one when loading is actually supposed to start, call the other when loading actually finishes, and you'll be all good.

Comment: Thanks for your patience but I it didn't work for me. See my new update. Why the first statement that executes is the `sleep` and not my first slide in animation?

Comment: If you were actually loading data that'd be different than using sleep. You should never really use sleep in an iPhone program. Take out sleep and do this:

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{ 
                     loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,40);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{ 
                     loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-40,320,40);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                 }];
      }];

Comment: I used the `sleep` for testing. The animation works fine but I would that the view slide in, stay for some seconds (for the time of the request) and when the request is completed it slides out. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is add a view in front of your other views with the loading design you want.

Then when the loading is finished (use a notification or just call a function of the view), slide it up with that kind of animation :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^{
                             //change the frame to make the view go out of the screen
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             //do whatever you want with the view (release it for instance)
                         }];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the help of spinner else you take just view and set animation with its coordinate when you click on any object it will popup n your view and after completion of loading it you have to set '-' coordinate(frame) for your popup view hop it will hekp you......